# Visual Basic 6 on Windows 10 (Yes, Really)

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, visual-basic, vb6

Is there any way to install VB6 on a Windows 10 machine?

I've been asked to revive and move an old company application from an XP machine to a new PC.  The code is going to be rewritten in C#, but we want to be able to run it "as is" until that upgrade is complete.

Comment: Have you considered virtualizing the XP system and running it on new hardware, until the application can be rebuilt?

Comment: I can be done, as I've done it more than once, but it's a major headache.  I do not have the steps necessary but suffice it to say it's not a "standard procedure."  There are some non-intuitive selections you have to make during the install process.  I got my information by googling it and I'm pretty sure my final solution is somewhere on stackoverflow with a vb6 tag (as I've added that tag to this question, but fewer posts are here than on stackoverflow).  I still develop and maintain my own accounting app in VB 6 running under Win 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "yes."  Microsoft's online documentation says the following:

> The VB6 runtime will ship and will be supported in Windows 10 for the
>   lifetime of the OS. Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files continue to be
>   32-bit only, and all components must be hosted in 32-bit application
>   processes.

Source: [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vb6/vb6-support)

Comment: Where can I get the actual IDE to install?

Comment: @SpecialKay - You would have to purchase a license to Visual Basic 6?  You would have to find a vendor selling a license along with the media to install it..  We will be unable to help you locate either

Comment: It might be available from MSDN.